# Windows phone development on visual studio 2012

Tags: windows, sdk

I have windows 7 and visual studio 2012 and want to start developing windows phone apps. Do I need an SDK? If yes, What version of the SDK is required?

Comment: just go to http://developer.windowsphone.com/ and read.  It can't be easier than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7, you need to use VS 2010 (full or express version) to develop for WP7 .

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/0e40579d-12a5-4aba-81cb-ab83e5956fc2/windows-7-visual-studio-2012-windows-phone-development?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

You need Windows 8 (or 8.1) to develop Windows Phone 8 applications, for which you can use the [Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).

You *cannot* use Windows 7 to develop native Windows Phone 8 apps. You can, if I recall, use the older [Windows Phone 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27570) with Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 but you're really limiting yourself with Windows Phone 7.